# The error occurs when it is call by RegisterClientScriptBlock on jQuery dialog box

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, jquery-ui

I open another internal page on the dialog box which is attached on div. After user input the data, I need to save on SQL and close the dialog box. I used  RegisterClientScriptBlock to call the jQuery script, but there is an error.
[image]

On the child page (Test2.aspx), there is the Cancel button to call the same script and it worked. Would someone tell me how to do it. Thanks in advance.

There is the parent aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Test1.aspx.vb" Inherits="Order.Test1" %>

<%--<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">--%>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
      <script src="include/dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-themes-1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />   
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-themes-1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
      <script  language="javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script language="javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script language="javascript" src="/include/dailog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


      <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnOrder').click(function (e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 openBox('Test2.aspx?id=0', 'Testing', 700, 650);

            });
        });
      </script>
    <title>Parent page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnOrder" runat="server" Text="Order" />

         <div id="dialog-box"/>
    </div>
    </form>    
</body>
</html>
```

There is the child page which is loaded on dialog box:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Test2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Test.Test2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
     <script language="javascript" src="dailog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>         
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnCancel').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                CloseDialogBox();
            });
     });
    </script>
    <title>Dialog Box</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" />

        <br />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my vb code:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     btnSave.Click
'Need to do something on backend and close dialog box
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "Script", "<script type='text/javascript'>CloseDialogBox();</script>", True)  
End Sub
```

Here is my jQuery script:

```
function openDailogBox(url, name, width, height) {  
$('#dialog-box').load(url).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true,
    height: height
    width: width,       
    title: name,
    modal: true,
   draggable: false

});
  $('#dialog-box').dialog('open');
 return false;
}


function CloseDialogBox() {   
    alert('Close');
    $('#dialog-box').dialog({

        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: true,     
        title: name,
        modal: true,

    });

    $('#dialog-box').dialog('close');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a closer look at your code snippet. I realized you are re- instantiating the dialog multiple times which will make it difficult to track which instance of the dialog was open on the page. Consider a single function handling the opening and closing of the dialog. You were also using dialog.js and the jquery-ui dialog at the same time.It will be easier to debug if you stick to one of these libraries. Write a single function like so:

```
function openDailogBox(url,height,width) {
if ($('#dialog-box').length==0) {
    $('body').append('<div id="dialog-box"></div>');
}

$('#dialog-box').dialog({
    width: width,
    height:height,
    autoOpen:false
});

if (url!==""){
    $('#dialog-box').load(url);
    $('#dialog-box').dialog('open');

}
else
{
   $('.ui-dialog').not(':last').remove(); //clear any extra dialogs created from the append
   $('#dialog-box').dialog('close');

    }
     }
```

I also removed that orphaned comma running awol in your jquery constructor in your initial **closedialog** function.

```
 $('#dialog-box').dialog({

    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true,     
    title: name,
    modal: true

});
```

I have made a sample project for you with the syntax errors fixed and with some sections of your code refactored. Kudos for trying. Set Test1.aspx as the start up page and modify the code to suit your taste. [Download sample working project here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_EJIxqB78zId0hGcXprQzR0TXM)

**Update.**

To solve the page reload issue for Test2.aspx

**Markup**

`<input id="btnSave" type="button"  value="Save"   /`>

**JS**

```
 $('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
$.ajax({
    url: 'yourwebserviceurl',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { field1: $('#TextBox1').val()} ,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (response) {
        //your success code
    },
    error: function () {
        //your error code
    }
}); 
        });
```

Comment: I modified the closedialog function as your mentioned, it doesn't work.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Donwload the zip file I attached and see a sample working project.

Comment: I downloaded your zip file and run it. You didn't add any code or script for btnSave. My problem is that after input the number on Test2.aspx then click the Save button. The test2.aspx is reload, not close. By the way, you added the code on btnOrder_Click on vb file. Do you want to add on Test2.aspx for btnSave. If so, it didn't work.  Thanks.

Comment: Test2.aspx is being reload because of the post back when you click the input button. Change your save button to an input, then on its click event make an ajax webservice call to save the info into the database. And this has nothing to do with the error you were getting in the first place.See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "CloseDialogBoxScript", "CloseDialogBox();", True)
```

Does that work? I was under the impression that the last parameter in RegisterClientScriptBlock indicates that script tags are code-generated. This means you do not have to add them in yourself.

Comment: without the last parameter "True", the child page is reload, not closed

Comment: You should leave the last parameter on. Just remove the script tags. Do you see how I am just calling CloseDialogBox() without putting script tags around it?

Comment: I tried your code. It is same the child page is reload, not closed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess 'CloseDialogBox' function exists on parent page and the button (btnSave) you are firing is in Child page (Test2.aspx). So the error JavaScript runtime error: 'CloseDialogBox' is undefined".

Comment: The cancel button is also called this function on child page but it is no problem. when it used 'Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock" , it has an error.